# How to implement out-of-home when developing an IOT device?

Tags: raspberry-pi, networking, sensors, philips-hue

I have a Raspberry Pi that tells you through web sockets and a sensor the amount of electricity you are spending in real time.

I created an iPhone app as a front-end that basically just paints the info received through the web socket.

Evidently, this does not work when you are not in the same local network and now I am testing different technologies to solve this problem.

**First option** is a VPN, when when selling this to hundreds of customers, that probably don't have advance technical skills, this will not work.

**Second option:** Ngrok. I use this for accessing my macmini jenkins outside my office, works really well, however, its price, about 2 or 3 dollars per year, is too much for a IOT device.

**Third option:** Nabto (www.nabto.com). It seems it is what I need, and only a few cents/pence per year. But, integrating that library in my app is a bit painful.

Does anyone have more ideas about how to solve this problem or libraries/solutions I could use?

By the way, does anyone what technology is used by Philips Hue?

Comment: I would use a public MQTT service. There are some free MQTT services. **PS** Next time you post, check how the text is formated before posting.

Comment: Can be MQTT  used for real time apps? My app sends hundreds of messages per second containing data that the app uses to draw a graph, that is the reason I use web sockets instead of http web services.
I thought MQTT was more like http services, I mean, a messaging protocol not in real time.

Comment: I didn't see the need for real time when measuring power consumption, and you are right about MQTT, its a messaging protocol.

Comment: I see another problem, it seems that approach requires an Internet connection all the time, it is less reliable than nabto (that works in the same network if there is no internet connection), or not having anything.

Comment: Have a look at RabittMQ, Ref.: https://www.rabbitmq.com that is well suited for distributed models, high volumes of messages and more.

Comment: HTTP != MQTT. HTTP is a synchronous request/response protocol. MQTT is a pub/sub messaging protocol, they are nothing alike. Also MQTT can easily handle 1000s of messages a second, but that is not even close to right approach for this type of problem, a display needs a cumulative value at no more than once a min and may be an instant update on a major change in instantaneous consumption (e.g. oven turn on)

Comment: i would get a cheap VPS, and run my own MQTT server on it, with whatever logging and auth methods i need and work non-painfully.

Answer (score 4):

You can (should) use a lightweight machine to machine protocol like MQTT which is designed for this purpose.

Documentation is sufficient and you can find a suitable library for a variety of programming languages.

You will find useful information about this messaging protocol on

> http://mqtt.org/documentation

You need to install a broker on a physical/virtual server in order to subscribe/publish on topics and access data out of the local network. In this case, mosquitto comes very handy and well structured which you can find enough information about it on

> https://mosquitto.org

Also, you can always use mosquitto's free broker in order to test your solution (It is not reliable for production scale), the broker address is :

> test.mosquitto.org

Finally, you can use MQTT based cloud platforms such as links mentioned below

> https://www.hivemq.com
>
> https://www.cloudmqtt.com
>
> https://myqtthub.com/en

Comment: Thanks Sina. Can I use MQTT for real time apps? Just to send a constant flow of data in order to paint a diagram in the app in real time.

Comment: Of course , depending on your server's performance and your internet speed. Please bear in mind, 1) you can set up your own Physical/Virtual Private server or 2) you can use an online platform, but the first scenario is more customizable and scalable.

Comment: I am going to try that. Last question, what about if the local network does not have Internet connection?

Comment: In this case you can not access your devices out of the local network (as I know), still your devices can communicate to each other through a local network and a server (like the Raspberry Pi you've mentioned). setting up a Mosquitto broker on a raspberry pi is easy and there are a lot of instructions regarding your RPi's operating system on the internet. check out https://www.switchdoc.com/2018/02/tutorial-installing-and-testing-mosquitto-mqtt-on-raspberry-pi/